# iOS12: transitionController was deprecated

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I have a `UIDocumentBrowser` based app which opens a specific type of files. The default transition for opening a file is sliding from bottom, which is not the nicest transition user can expect. Before iOS 12 with this piece you could get a zoom transition, it does work now too, but the compiler is complaining about using `transitionController(forDocumentURL:)` which is deprecated. How can I have this effect in iOS 12 way?

```
func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let documentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
    documentViewController.document = Document(fileURL: documentURL)
    // 
    documentViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    let transitioningController = transitionController(forDocumentURL: documentURL)
    transitioningController.targetView = documentViewController.view
    self.transitioningController = transitioningController
    //
    present(documentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the parameter has just been changed and you can just replace `forDocumentURL` with [`forDocumentAt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller/3019587-transitioncontroller):

```
let transitioningController = transitionController(forDocumentAt: documentURL)
```

Comment: How careless I am! Thanks.

Comment: It’s not your fault. Usually deprecation annotations supply the replacement method, and they didn’t here. Plus, the documentation is woefully incomplete (not only the missing reference to the replacement method, the documentation for the new method is empty; lol).

Comment: Yes, I hope they fix these problems for the next release.

Comment: Not as of Xcode 10.2 beta 4, yet. I’ve filed bug report #48854007.